# Are all singleton methods public?

Tags: ruby, singleton-methods

Is a singleton method necessarily public? If not, when would a private/protected singleton method be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Singleton methods do not necessarily need to be public. Private/protected singleton methods are useful in the same situations as regular private/protected methods - for example as a helper method that you do not intend to be called outside of the class.

```
class Foo
end

f = Foo.new

class << f
  def foo
    helper
    # other stuff
  end

  private
  def helper
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a singleton method private if you want:

```
class Foo
end

f = Foo.new
def f.bar
  "baz"
end

f.singleton_class.send :private, :bar
f.bar # => NoMethodError: private method `bar' called for #<Foo:0x007f8674152a00>
f.send :bar # => "baz"
```

whether or not this is actually useful depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a singleton method private if you want:

```
class Foo

  def self.bar
    # ...
  end
  private_class_method :bar

end
```

Comment: BTW: in recent versions of Ruby, method definition expressions (`def`) evaluate to a `Symbol` corresponding to the name of the method being defined, so that you can do `private_class_method def self.bar; end` or `protected def foo; end` or something like that.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question of 'Are all singleton methods public?'

Comment: @hichris123, do we need more than one singleton method that is not public to disprove the assertion that they are all public?

Answer (score 0):

Could they be useful? Hmmm. For Ruby 2.2

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).flat_map { |m|
  m.singleton_class.private_methods(false) }.size
  #=> 900
```

Most are private methods of classes' singleton classes:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).flat_map { |c|
  c.singleton_class.private_methods(false) }.size
  #=> 838
```

[Edit: The following is an edit of my original post, to present more useful information.)

I am puzzled by one thing. Let:

```
a = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).map { |c|
      [c, c.singleton_class.private_methods(false)] }.to_h

b = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).map { |c|
      [c, c.private_methods(false)] }.to_h

def diff(a,b) 
  a.map {|k,v| b.key?(k) ? [k,v-b[k]] : [k,v] }.reject { |_,a| a.empty?}.to_h
end
```

I expected `diff(a,b) == diff(b,a) == {}`. Let's see:

```
diff(a,b)
  #=> {} 

diff(b,a)
  #=> {Gem::Specification=>[:skip_during, :deprecate],
  #    Complex=>[:convert],
  #    Rational=>[:convert],
  #    Random=>[:state, :left],
  #    Time=>[:_load]}
```

Hmmmm.